# Filter (dedupe) and concat csv files

Tags: clojure

A tip request please:

How can I concat a set of large csv files into one.  I need rows identified as duplicates removed (i.e. filter  (some #{s} (get row 1) ) Each file has no duplicates, actually, only between the files can duplicate rows appear.  The order of the final outputs isn't crucial, but matching a sequential scan of the files would be preferred.

The total number of ids to maintain is about 150,000,000, so maintaining a set that large in memory is doable, I think.

So, I've got a a fn that takes a filename and a set of ids to avoid and returns a filtered sequence of rows.  I've also got a vector of filenames to process.  I can't wrap my head around how to output the filtered rows to a single file while conj the ids from each filtered set of rows into an existing set.

```
(defn open-seq "read file f and filter rows based on set s" [f s]
   (letfn [(iset? [x]
             (let [ls (s/split x #", ")
                   id (read-string (get ls 1))]
               (not (some #{id} s))))]
(with-open [in (io/reader f)]
  (->> (line-seq in)
       (filter iset?)
     ; shortcut  (take 20)
       doall)
  ))
```

)

EDIT:

This is a two-pass solution.

```
(defn proc [infiles outfile]
  (with-open [outf (io/writer outfile)]
   (let [s (atom #{})]
     (doseq [infile infiles]
      (with-open [in (io/reader infile)]
       (doseq [line (open-seq in @s)]
        (.write outf line)
        (.newLine outf)))
      (with-open [in (io/reader infile)]
       (let [ids (->> (open-seq in @s)
                     (map (fn [x] (get x 1))))]
        (swap! s conj ids)
        ))
    ))))
```

I suppose I could conj each id onto the set atom with each line.  I guess that had a preconceived notion that conjing the whole seq of ids would be more idiomatic.

Comment: How big are the files? If they are small enough to process in memory, it's trivial. If not you'd have to keep track of lines seen as you scan the files and write the output (unless your files are sorted, in that case just proceed sequentially on both and skip dupes).

Comment: Following up on Diego Basch's comment, if the files are small, you can use [`read.csv`](http://clojure.github.io/data.csv/) to read them into lazy sequences, and then there are several ways to proceed.  Brody is right that you should show that you've tried to solve the problem on your own and explain how, or explain where you've gotten stuck in the process of learning.

Comment: I know you asked to do it in clojure but this is a one liner on the command line. `cat .. | sort -u`

Comment: So I added my own solution that does in job, but requires two passes through each file.  Is there a straightforward way to do it in one pass?